# Is there Visual Studio Android Emulator for Noughat (7.0 or7.1.1)

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

How to update Emulator for API level 24 and 25.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. The Visual Studio Emulator for Android does not support API levels greater than 23.

Comment: Now this is weird , since VS emulator is installed which is hyper-v based, I can't install android emulator by google as they will be VMware or virtualbox based and hyper-v conflicts with VMware and virtual box.

Comment: You can install them, but they won't be hardware accelerated. Haxm doesn't work when hyper v is enabled. You can do one or the other.